# Partially search words in a TABLE with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I use Javascript to search within a HTML table column. However, I can only search a value by typing the first letters of the table cells content.

An example of my data is shown below.

If I search for the value **123** in *column 2*, the desired table cell pops up like it should.

If I search for the value **456** or **23** for example , nothing happens.

```
|column1|column2|
__________________
|000|123 456|
|001|123 456|
```

My current Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#searchn").on("keyup", function() {
            var value = $(this).val();

            $("table tr").each(function(index) {
                if (index !== 0) {

                    $row = $(this);

                    var id = $row.find("td").children().eq(1).text();

                    if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                        $row.hide();
                    }
                    else {
                        $row.show();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is flawed as `indexOf()` returns `-1` if the value you're searching for is not found, and the zero-based index of the match if it was found. Because of this, your `if` statement is flawed as it excludes matches at the start of the value.

You should change your `if` condition to this instead:

```
if (id.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
    $row.hide();
}
else {
    $row.show();
}
```

Also note that you can shorten this by using `filter()` and `toggle()` instead:

```js
$("#searchn").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val();

  $("table tr:not(:first)").show().filter(function(index) {
      return $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text().indexOf(value) == -1;
  }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>000</td>
    <td>123 456</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>001</td>
    <td>123 456</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input id="searchn" />
```

Comment: Works like a charm :)! Thank you for your explanation and clear example.

Comment: No problem,  glad to help